# Finite-to-one continuous factor map preserves entropy?

Tags: dynamical-systems, entropy, ergodic-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact metric spaces with Borel $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$. Let $S: X \to X$ and $T: Y \to Y$ be homeomorphisms. Let $\pi: X \to Y$ be a bounded-to-one continuous factor map, i.e. $\pi$ is surjective, $\pi \circ S = T \circ \pi$, and for some $1 \leq M < \infty$ and all $y \in Y$, $\mathrm{card} \,\pi^{-1}(\{ y \}) \leq M$. Let $\mu$ be an $S$-invariant Borel probability measure on $(X, \mathcal{B})$, and equip $(Y, \mathcal{C})$ with the $T$-invariant measure $\nu = \pi_* \mu$.

Is it the case that $h_{\nu}(T) = h_{\mu}(S)$? If so, how much can my hypotheses be weakened?

I have tried to apply the Abramov-Rokhlin formula, which states that
$$
h_{\mu}(S) = h_{\nu}(T) + h_{\mu}(S \, | \, T)
$$
where $h_{\mu}(S \, | \, T) = h_{\mu}( S \, | \, \pi^{-1} \mathcal{C} )$ is the relative entropy. I think I should be able to use the bounded-to-one hypothesis to show that this relative entropy is $0$, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: why can't you take $Y=X, \pi = id$ and then just $\mu,\nu$ different measures? like $X$ is a Bernoulli shift on two symbols and $\mu = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}, \nu = \frac{1}{3}-\frac{2}{3}$; the entropies are different. maybe im missing something

Comment: Oops! You're very right. Forgot the extremely point that $\nu = \pi_* \mu$. Will edit the question.

Comment: Have you looked at the case of symbolic spaces, let's say with 4 and 2 symbols with the map 0,2 -> 0 and 1,3 -> 1, and see what happens with the uniform measure in this setting?

Comment: @FelipePérez If you mean the full $4$-shift mapping to the full $2$-shift, this is not finite-to-one. If for the domain you mean a pair of disjoint copies of the full $2$-shift (one with alphabet $\{0,2\}$, one with alphabet $\{ 1,3  \}$) each carrying a scaled uniform measure, I've tried playing with generators there (tried to show that a generator for $T$ lifts to one for $S$) but haven't actually done the entropy calculation! I'll try that.

Comment: @SophieMacDonald what did u mean "if for the domain you mean..."? can u describe that setup for me plz

Comment: @mathworker21 I just mean if $X$ (the domain of $\pi$) is the disjoint union of two full $2$-shifts, i.e. $X = \{ 0,1  \}^{\mathbb{Z}} \cup \{ 2,3 \}^{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: Also in my reply to @FelipePérez, it should have been $\{0,1\}$ and $\{2,3\}$, not $\{0,2\}$ and $\{1,3\}$.

Comment: @SophieMacDonald entropy is obv log2 in either case

Comment: @mathworker21 yes, but with the block map proposed ($0,2 \mapsto 0$; $1,3 \mapsto 1$), my original statement would have sent the pair of $2$-shifts to a pair of points.

Comment: @SophieMacDonald idk what u mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, by an Abramov-Rohlin type formula of Ledrappier and Walters ("A relativised variational principle for continuous transformations", p.569, Thm.2.1; they prove the statement for pressure).

**Theorem (Ledrappier-Walters):** Let $X,Y$ be compact metric, $S:X\to X$, $T:Y\to Y$ be continuous, $\pi:X\to Y$ be a continuous surjection such that $\pi\circ S=T\circ \pi$ (so that $T$ is a topological factor of $S$). Then for any $\nu\in\operatorname{Prob}(Y,T)$:

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{ent}_{\nu}(T) 
&\leq \inf_{\substack{\mu\in\operatorname{Prob(X,S)}\\\pi_\ast(\mu)=\nu}} \operatorname{ent}_{\mu}(S) \\
&\leq \sup_{\substack{\mu\in\operatorname{Prob(X,S)}\\\pi_\ast(\mu)=\nu}} \operatorname{ent}_{\mu}(S)
= \operatorname{ent}_{\nu}(T) + \int_Y \operatorname{topent}(S;\pi^{-1}(y))\, d\nu(y).
\end{align*}

Here $\operatorname{topent}(S;\pi^{-1}(y))$ is defined using $(S,n,\epsilon)$-separated subsets of $\pi^{-1}(y)$ (or sets that $(S,n,\epsilon)$-span $\pi^{-1}(y)$), and $y\mapsto \operatorname{topent}(S;\pi^{-1}(y))$ is measurable. When a fiber $\pi^{-1}(y)$ is finite it's straighforward that $\operatorname{topent}(S;\pi^{-1}(y))=0$; when each fiber is finite (not necessarily uniformly so) the integral on the RHS vanishes.

---

Let me also mention that this theorem builds on an analogous theorem on topological entropy of Bowen:

**Theorem (Bowen):** With $X,Y,S,T,\pi$ as in the previous theorem,

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{topent}(T) 
&\leq \operatorname{topent}(S) \\
&\leq \operatorname{topent}(T) + \sup_{y\in Y}  \operatorname{topent}(S;\pi^{-1}(y)).
\end{align*}

Bowen's proof of this is combinatorial, and the theorem gives the topological version of what you are asking. Of course via the variational principle the Ledrappier-Walters formula also gives it. Robinson's *Dynamical Systems: Stability, Symbolic Dynamics, and Chaos* has a proof of the uniformly finite fibers case for the topological entropy (p.340,Thm.1.8 of the first edition). I haven't read it but one might be able to adapt it to bypass Ledrappier-Walters.